# Как простой функцией SpawnObject(string object) выбрать параметры для этого объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть базовый для объекта класс с кучей параметров:

```
public class BasicObject {
private string objectName;
    public string ObjectName
    {
        get { return objectName; }
        set { objectName = value; }
    }
private int mass; // и так же public поля
private int param;
private int spriteIndex;
// еще куча всего, но для краткости опустим

public BasicObject (string objectName, int mass, int param, int spriteIndex)
{
this.objectName = objectName;
this.mass = mass;
this.param = param;
this.spriteIndex = spriteIndex;
}
```

И есть класс, в котором я спавню нужный мне объект (сам класс висит на `GameObject` на сцене):

```
public class ObjectSpawnerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject basicObjectPrefab;

    public Sprite[] sprites;

    private static ObjectSpawnerScript instance;
    public static ObjectSpawnerScript Instance 
    {
        get {
            if (instance == null) 
            {
                instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ObjectSpawnerScript> ();
            }
            return ObjectSpawnerScript.instance; }
    }


// я хочу заспавнить нужный мне объект с нужными параметрами, используя только его имя
    private void SpawnObject (string objectName)
    {
        GameObject myObject = (GameObject)Instantiate (basicObjectPrefab);

        ChooseObject(objectName, myObject);
    }

    private void ChooseObject(string objName, GameObject obj)
    {

// вот от этой конструкции не могу придумать, как избавиться
        if (objName == "object_1_box_type_1") {
            BasicObjectScript newObject = new BasicObjectScript (objectName, 10, 42, 0);
            obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprites[newObject.SpriteIndex];
        } else if (objName == "object_1_box_type_2") {
            BasicObjectScript newObject = new BasicObjectScript (objectName, 15, 42, 1);
            obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprites[newObject.SpriteIndex];
        }
// а вот это мне нравится - я просто указываю, что хочу от полученного объекта
// и мне не нужно это делать для КАЖДОГО if - else
        obj.transform.position = new Vector2 (2, 0);
        obj.name = objName;

    }
```

Ну и, как и написано в вопросе, я хочу просто написать `SpawnObject("имя_объекта")` и чтобы у меня по этому имени выбрались параметры для этого объекта. Сейчас для этого я делаю `if (objName == "object_1_box_type_1")`, но мне это очень не нравится. Можно ведь обойтись без сравнений?

Comment: Тебе в любом случае где-то придется указывать/задавать значения. Либо ты сделай словарь `dict`, где ключом будет имя, а значением объект с параметрами и тогда достаточно будет в методе `ChooseObject` брать из словаря по ключу `dict[objName]`. Либо создай `.asset` на каждый объект со своими настройками и подгружай `asset` по имени `objName` с его индивидуальными настройками........ кстати, в твоем примере можно просто сделать `switch/case` а строку `obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprites[newObject.SpriteIndex];` вообще вынести из условий, ведь она повторяется.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский c `dictionary` щас попробую, `.asset` загуглю. `switch/case` ругается, что `newObject` уже определен раньше (хотя, может, я его неправильно делаю. Но так же он ругается, если я делаю `if-else ` без скобок). `sprites[newObject.SpriteIndex]` не могу вынести из условий - пишет `[newObject.SpriteIndex]` "не существует"

Comment: `switch/case ругается, что newObject уже определен раньше` - потому что надо **один раз** определить переменную `BasicObjectScript newObject = null;` или хотя бы какое-то дефолтное значение, а потом в `switch/case` в нее пихать значения.........`[newObject.SpriteIndex] "не существует"` - аналогично предыдущему.. все потому, что ты вынес из контекста...... соответстевнно и `BasicObjectScript newObject` надо определять **до** условий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ух ты - не знал. Сделал с `Dictionary`: `public Dictionary<int, BasicObjectScript> objects = new Dictionary<int, BasicObjectScript>();`, ну и функцию `private void AddObjectsInDictionary()
 {
  objects.Add (0, "object_1_box_type_1", 10, 42, 0);
  // и все объекты, какие хочу. Индекс лучше - на строку будет ругаться - мол, уже существует в словаре
 }`. Ее вызываю в `Awake()`

Comment: `на строку будет ругаться - мол, уже существует в словаре` - разве для уникального имени не будут свои конкретные данные? если - да, то ключ надо именно строковый. а по индексу ты как определишь какой объект у тебя где? например в индексе под номером 634 какой? Перебирать все, пока не найдешь? А если у тебя один тип объекта может иметь разные размеры. значит надо в классе делать Min max для генерируемых данных и исходить из них.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня на сцене могут находиться несколько одинаковых объектов одновременно. Вообще, доступ к любой информации об объекте я могу получить так: `objects[0].ObjectName` или  `objects[0].SpriteIndex`, но с цифрами, конечно, не так удобно работать (чисто визуально).` если у тебя один тип объекта может иметь разные размеры` - `Min max` неплохая идея, можно еще в `BasicObject` добавить `width` и `height`, на которые он будет влиять

Comment: Тебе нужно проектирование на шаблонах, и ты изобретаешь собственные префабы. В Unity уже есть префабы, ты можешь создать их заранее, а затем инстанциировать  процессе игры. Можешь держать их во внешних файлах, например, в .CSV-таблицах.

Comment: @LunarWhisper я не хочу в проекте иметь кучу префабов (мне просто не нравится, как этот список будет выглядеть), вместо этого я использую всего 1 префаб, на который и вешаю необходимые "данные". "Можешь держать их во внешних файлах, например, в .CSV-таблицах" - щас посмотрю, как это делается

Comment: `я не хочу в проекте иметь кучу префабов (мне просто не нравится, как этот список будет выглядеть), вместо этого я использую всего 1 префаб, на который и вешаю необходимые "данные"` - тогда вообще тебе зачем все эти условия с `if (objName == "object_1_box_type_1"` ? непонятно.. короч. тебе нужно скорее всего копать именно в сторону `asset`, в котором будут прописаны и храниться данные: типы объектов и их параметры. Например `evilMob.asset` или `goodMob.asset` и просто генерировать рандомный тип и брать данные из ассета. кмк нужно что-то такое... хотя может я не до конца понял всю задумку

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

Если вы не хотите создавать кучу префабов, и, хотите создавать простой объект потом присваивать ему какие-то параметры, то вам необходимо создать простую базу данных для своей игры! Могу посоветовать простенькую утилиту для удобства работы [JsonObject](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710).

Скачайте и установите себе в проект.

Далее для работы с ней вам понадобится создать файл внутри проекта с расширением `.json`. например: `MyDatabase.json` и заполнить ее необходимыми для вас параметрами. К примеру я написал так:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "box_type_1",
        "mass": 10,
        "param": 123,
        "sprite_index": 0,
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "box_type_2",
        "mass": 20,
        "param": 234,
        "sprite_index": 1,
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "box_type_3",
        "mass": 50,
        "param": 1000,
        "sprite_index": 2,
        "active": false
    }
]
```

Далее считываем данные из этого файла и записываем в словарь уже **готовые** параметры:

```
public class BasicObject {
    //...
    //...
    public BasicObject(JSONObject json) { // объявляем новый конструктор класса для удобства и красоты
        this.objectName = json["name"].str;
        this.mass = (int)json["mass"].i;
        this.param = (int)json["param"].i;
        this.spriteIndex = (int)json["sprite_index"].i;
        //this.active = json["active"].b; //например такое можно добавить
    }
}

public TextAsset myDataBase; //сюда ручками или же используя Resources.Load загружаете свой файл с базой данных
Dictionary<string, BasicObject> m_Objects; // тут будут храниться настройки для ваших объектов

void Start() {
    m_Objects = new Dictionary<string, BasicObject>();
    if (myDataBase != null) {
        JSONObject jsonBase = new JSONObject(myDataBase.text);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonBase.Count; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonData = jsonBase[i];
            m_Objects.Add(jsonData["name"].str, new BasicObject(jsonData));// сохраняем считанные данные в словарь
            // желательно бы тут по идентификаторам сохранять, это все на ваше усмотрение
            //m_Objects.Add((int)jsonData["id"].i, new BasicObject(jsonData));
        }
    }
    //foreach (BasicObject obj in m_Objects.Values) { // для теста
    //    Debug.Log("name = " + obj.ObjectName + "    sprite index = " + obj.SpriteIndex);
    //}
}
```

И наконец спавним ваш объект:

```
private void ChooseObject(string objName, GameObject obj) {
     if (!m_Objects.ContainsKey(objName)) {
        Debug.LogError("объекта под таким именем не существует! >=(");
        return;
    }
    BasicObject b_object = m_Objects[objName];
    obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[b_object.SpriteIndex];
    obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = b_object.mass;
    obj.transform.position = new Vector2(2, 0);
    obj.name = objName;
}
```

Comment: зачем такой хардкор с json? а если хочется поиграться с настройками и нужно тонко выстроить что-то? Особенно с запущенной игрой. А если добавлять или удалять лишние поля? А если от выставляемого типа захочется сделать зависимость второго параметра?  Откройте для себя `scriptable object` и хранение данных в `.asset` и небольшие усилия сделать EditorWindow для редактирования оных. Хотя последнее не обязательно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо за подсказку, даже не знал о существовании `ScriptableObject`! Что скажу в свою защиту, это, пусть учится, хотя бы узнает что такое и как пользоваться `Json'ами`. Век живи - век учись, ну или, ученье - свет, а неученье - тьма! о.о